# Some inequalities for an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, complex-integration

Let, $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ be an entire function and let $r$ be a positive real number. Then, which is(/are) correct?

(a) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^{2}r^{2n}\le \sup_{|z|=r} |f(z)|^{2}$.

(b) $\sup_{|z|=r} |f(z)|^{2}\le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^{2}r^{2n}$.

(c) $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^{2}r^{2n}\le \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\bigl|f\bigl(re^{i\theta}\bigr)\bigr|^{2}d\theta$.

(d) $\sup_{|z|=r} |f(z)|^{2}\le \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\bigl|f\bigl(re^{i\theta}\bigr)\bigr|^{2}d\theta$.

This problem appeared as the No.82 problem in CSIR-UGC(NET) Mathematical Sciences Exam Paper, from New Delhi IMS in 2014, see this [pdf](http://www.ims4maths.com/coaching/files/Downloads/CSIR-UGC-NET-Exam-DEC-2014.pdf)

I  tried using Cauchy's inequality but I can't proceed further.

Comment: Note: whether $f$ is entire or not is immaterial. Only that $f$ is defined on a disk $D_R(0)$ for some $R > r$ is required. Tips: Start with d) and work backwards to a).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of Cauchy's formula, you need Parseval's formula.
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|^2r^{2n} = \frac1{2\pi} \int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\big|f(r^{it})\big|^2 \mathrm{d}t.
$$

So we have equality in (c) and the trivial estimate 
$\frac1{2\pi} \int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\big|f(r^{it})\big|^2 \mathrm{d}t \le \sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|^2$ in (a).

(b) and (d) are equivalent and false; try $f(z)=1+z$.